# mysql won´t create me an foreign key, cause no index in referenced table (but index exist!)

Tags: mysql, database

Moin moin (like we in Hamburg say),
i wanted to add a column with a foreign key in a existing table with filled records. and referencing the key to another table with primary key. so far so good.

But i can´t cause mysql says me that the index for the referenced table is not existing. But it actually does. so i don´t know, what´s the point is.

the error:

> 2017-04-11 19:21:08 0x1770 Error in foreign key constraint of table animals/#sql
>   -7a0_7:
>   foreign key(pet_id) references pet (pet_id):
>   Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
>   referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
>   in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.

the referenced table:

```
+---------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| pet_id  | int(3) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name    | varchar(20)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| owner   | varchar(20)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| species | varchar(10)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sex     | char(1)         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| birth   | date            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| death   | date            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and the index:

```
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+------
-------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardi
nality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+------
-------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| pet   |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | pet_id      | A         |
     9 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| pet   |          1 | pet_id   |            1 | pet_id      | A         |
     9 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| pet   |          1 | pet_id   |            2 | name        | A         |
     9 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| pet   |          1 | pet_id   |            3 | owner       | A         |
     9 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| pet   |          1 | pet_id   |            4 | species     | A         |
     9 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| pet   |          1 | pet_id   |            5 | sex         | A         |
     9 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| pet   |          1 | pet_id   |            6 | birth       | A         |
     9 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| pet   |          1 | pet_id   |            7 | death       | A         |
     9 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+------
-------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
8 rows in set (0.10 sec)
```

if it helps............

**UPDATE:** result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE pet`:

```
| pet   | CREATE TABLE `pet` (
`pet_id` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`owner` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`species` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`sex` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`birth` date DEFAULT NULL,
`death` date DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`pet_id`),
KEY `pet_id` (`pet_id`,`name`,`owner`,`species`,`sex`,`birth`,`death`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

Comment: what is the query you ran to get the error?

Comment: can you show the result of running `SHOW CREATE TABLE animal` that will also help

Comment: `ALTER TABLE event ADD pet_id int(3), ADD FOREIGN KEY(pet_id) REFERENCES pet(pet_id)` - the query

Comment: ok tried it now step by step. and added the column 'pet_id' to the table 'event'. but the foreign key, won´t be further setted....

now the query: `ALTER TABLE event ADD CONSTRAINT FK_pet_id FOREIGN KEY(pet_id) REFERENCES pet(pet_id);`